# help with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Is my solution right?

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}\right) &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(1+2+3+\cdots+n-1\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{(n-1)(1+n-1)}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-1}{2n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah. absolutely.

Comment: You could say first that you are using the known formula $1+2+\cdots +n-1=n(n-1)/2$. Then the second step can be omitted - which is better. This $1+n-1$ is a bit distracting anyway.

Comment: thank you my friend

Comment: I would skip that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ bit too.

Comment: @DanielG. You know that you have to '@' the user you are sending the comment in order to notify them right?

Comment: If you pair the terms from both sides, you get $\frac n2$ terms $\frac1n$ and a neglectable correction.

Answer (score 2):

Correct solution. Another way is to use Riemann sums:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac k{n^2}
&=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn-\frac1n
\end{align*}
and\begin{align*}
\lim_n\left(\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac kn\right)=\int_0^1x\;dx=\frac12.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely correct. Although while writing the second line, I think it would be better to write $$1+2+3+\cdots+\color{red}{(}n-1\color{red}{)}$$ instead of $$1+2+3+\cdots+n-1$$
as it may be interpreted as the sum to $n$ and then subtracting a $1$.

Have a good day :)

Comment: I do not see any issue with this answer since the question shows an attempt and is therefore not a low-quality question. Which other reason is there for a downvote ? (+1)